# Converting list to array and reshaping?

Tags: python, numpy

Attempting to make an array of 2d points.

```
import random
import numpy as np

world_x=500
world_y=500

num_points = 7
points_list = []

def fill_points():
    for i in range(num_points):
        points_list.append(random.randrange(-1*world_x,world_x+1))
        points_list.append(random.randrange(-1*world_y,world_y+1))
    points_array = np.array(points_list)
    points_array.reshape((num_points,2))
    print(points_array)
    print (points_array[0,])
    print (points_array[2,])
    print (points_array[4,])

fill_points()
```

Returns

```
[ -70 -491 -326  -35 -408  407   94 -330 -493  499  -61  -12   62 -357]
-70
-326
-408
```

I was expecting `[-70,-491],[-408,-407]`, and `[-493,499]`.  I've also tried to do this just using shape instead of reshape, and got similar results.  Am I converting the list incorrectly, or using reshape incorrectly?

Comment: `.reshape` returns a *new object*

Comment: I see, if anyone else is wondering, you can just reassign the new object to the variable name `points_array=points_array.reshape((num_points,2))` though @ktzr's solution below saves a line.

Comment: Well, you assign to *variables*, not objects. It doesn't make sense to say "reassign to itself*. You could assign it to a new variable or to the same variable, and use that variable to access the object, it is up to you. See my answer for an option that works in-place as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.reshape` method *returns a new array object*, that is, it doesn't work in-place. You can either reassign the results of `reshape` back to the same variable, or modify the `.shape` attribute directly, which does work in-place:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.arange(10)

In [3]: arr
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: arr.reshape(2, 5)
Out[4]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [5]: arr
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

On the other hand:

```
In [6]: arr.shape = 2, 5

In [7]: arr
Out[7]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Or use the `.resize` method for in-place modifications:

```
In [8]: arr = np.arange(4)

In [9]: arr
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [10]: arr.resize(2, 2)

In [11]: arr
Out[11]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Note: the different array objects can share the *same underlying buffer*, so be aware that this happens:

```
In [12]: arr = np.arange(10)

In [13]: arr
Out[13]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [14]: arr2 = arr.reshape(2, 5)

In [15]: arr
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [16]: arr2
Out[16]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [17]: arr[0] = 99

In [18]: arr
Out[18]: array([99,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])

In [19]: arr2
Out[19]:
array([[99,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])
```

So, this makes the re-assigning approach relatively cheap:

```
In [20]: arr = arr.reshape(2, 5)

In [21]: arr
Out[21]:
array([[99,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])
```

Note, I tend to avoid `.resize`, because you can accidentally do:

```
In [33]: arr = np.arange(4)

In [34]: arr.resize(4,4)

In [35]: arr
Out[35]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But it will at least warn you... if other arrays are referenced:

```
In [36]: arr = np.arange(4)

In [37]: arr2 = arr.reshape(2,2)

In [38]: arr
Out[38]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [39]: arr2
Out[39]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [40]: arr.resize(4,4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-c4464d98ed0e> in <module>()
----> 1 arr.resize(4,4)

ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function
```

However, you can override that behavior at your own peril:

```
In [41]: arr.resize(4,4, refcheck=False)

In [42]: arr
Out[42]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [43]: arr2
Out[43]:
array([[4611686018427387904, 4611686018427387904],
       [                  6,                   0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to keep the x and y cords together, try adding them as a list. E.g.:

```
import random
import numpy as np

world_x=500
world_y=500

num_points = 7
points_list = []

def fill_points():
    for i in range(num_points):
        points_list.append([random.randrange(-1*world_x,world_x+1),
                            random.randrange(-1*world_y,world_y+1)])
    points_array = np.array(points_list)
    print(points_array)
    print (points_array[0,0])
    print (points_array[2,0])
    print (points_array[4,0])

fill_points()
```

Outputs:

```
[[ 354 -147]
 [ 193  288]
 [ 157 -319]
 [ 133  426]
 [-109  -54]
 [ -61  224]
 [-251 -411]]
354
157
-109
```

Or if you want to use reshape. Remember reshape returns a new list, it doesnt change the list you input:

```
def fill_points():
    for i in range(num_points):
        points_list.append(random.randrange(-1*world_x,world_x+1))
        points_list.append(random.randrange(-1*world_y,world_y+1))
    points_array = np.array(points_list).reshape((num_points,2))
    print(points_array)
    print (points_array[0,0])
    print (points_array[2,0])
    print (points_array[4,0])

fill_points()
```